# How can I make a TDate parameter optional in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, parameters

My class looks like this;

```
type TBatchFilter = class(TObject)
  private
    FBatchNo: string;
    FLine: string;
    FCutoffDate: TDate;
  public
    constructor Create(ABatchNo, ALine: string; ACutoffDate: TDate); overload;
    constructor Create(ABatchFilter: TBatchFilter); overload;
    property BatchNo: string read FBatchNo;
    property Line: string read FLine;
    property CutoffDate: TDate read FCutoffDate;
end;
```

I want to make the ACutoffDate:TDate parameter optional. I was thing of calling the constructor like this;

```
MyBatchFilter := TBatchFilter('BATCH1', 'LINE1', nil);
```

Then in the constructor have something like this;

```
if (ACuttoffDate = nil) then
  dosomething
else
  dosomethingelse;
```

But i can't pass nil as a parameter.
I don't really want to overload the constructor any further.

Comment: if you don't want to change ACutoffDate to a Variant or Class you might use 0 which represents '18991230'

Comment: I have used this method as my solution. I would accept this if it was offered as an answer not a comment.

Comment: FWIW, I use `-693594.0` as a constant (`NULL_DATE`), which equates to `01/01/0001`. You can then use NULL_DATE as default value for the parameter, and it's easy to differentiate between an intentionally empty date value and an uninitialized (zero value) date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two obvious ways to tackle this:

1. Add another overloaded constructor that omits the date parameter.
2. Make the date parameter have a default value that is some sentinel value that has no meaning.

You've attempted to use `nil` as a sentinel, but the sentinel has to be a valid value for the type. And `nil` is not. You'll need to pick a suitable value. Perhaps zero. Or a very large positive or negative value. Whatever you choose, declare a named constant to give your code semantic clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value by pointer:

```
constructor Create(ABatchNo, ALine: string; ACutoffDate: PDate = nil); overload;
```

```
if (ACuttoffDate = nil) then
  dosomething
else
  dosomethingelse(ACuttoffDate^);
```

```
TBatchFilter.Create('123', 'line');
```

```
TBatchFilter.Create('123', 'line', @SomeDateVar);
```

Comment: This makes calling the function very awkward. Cannot pass function return values because there is nothing to take the address of. It forces you to put the date into a variable. A `Nullable<TDateTime>` would be a viable option. But I don't think anyone would do this.

Comment: The question was how to make a parameter optional, not how to pass a value to it. Personally, I would use an `overload` in this situation, but the OP forbid that. A sentinel value is fine, as long as a the data type has a sentinel that makes sense (which `TDate` does, but other types might not). Otherwise, a pointer makes it clear whether "I have a value" or not, especially in versions that do not have `Nullable<T>` available.

Comment: That's all fine. My only point is that the requirement to have a variable makes this approach exceedingly painful. Without any compensating benefits, it is not to be recommended.